# Android and bluetooth scatternet formation

Tags: android, bluetooth

could somebody help me about how piconects and scatternet networks are created on bluetooth? are them created by the bluetooth stack protocol following some kind of internal algorithm, or is something the user has to code on an application level?

If i want to create a scatternet network with android devices, how do you think would be the best strategy to create the maximum number of piconets inside the same scatternet, so i can achieve a maximum of 7 slaves devices per piconet, and like this way i dont have to manage parked devices?

thank you very much in advance

Answer (score 2):

For android, you will have to code this at the application level. [BtClickCompeteLink](http://code.google.com/p/apps-for-android/source/browse/trunk/BTClickLinkCompete/?r=157) is the perfect place to start. It basically creates a piconet, 1 master and 7 slaves.

To create a scatternet you will have to modified the client side of that code to accept connections after it has made the connection itself to the master. So if you can imagine the format of the tree: every slave to the main Master will then become masters of 7 other slaves, those 7 other slaves then become masters to (7x7 = 49) other slaves. And so forth and so forth. But there is an upper limit to how many piconets may exist within one area, I believe it was 10 or so.

Comment: Link 404s, this one works though: https://github.com/mitchellhislop/apps-for-android/tree/master/BTClickLinkCompete, or this: https://code.google.com/p/apps-for-android/source/browse/#git%2FBTClickLinkCompete